# formatting a date with variables in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, date

I am trying to format a date so I can use a compare function to sort the data

```
$(xml).find("item").each(function () {
            var dateText = $(this).find("Date").text();
            var year = dateText.substr(0,4);
            var month = dateText.substr(4,2) ;
            var day = dateText.substring(6,2);
            var newDate = new Date(year, month, day);
```

When I display the newDate I get this: Mon Jul 03 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time) which isn't close to the actual dates which are in 2013 and 2014. Does anyone have a suggestion as to formating this correctly? Thanks!

Comment: Well, this will depend on the format your XML date is in. Take a look at what format it is in, and adjust the `substring()` calls accordingly (or feed it directly to the `Date` object if it's a compatible format)

Comment: The format is yyyymmdd

Comment: also, about 40 entries have this date element. the remaining elements do not have it. Could this the problem?

Comment: You'll really have to look at the data. `console.log(dateText); console.log(year); console.log(month); console.log(day);` will show you what data it's working with and what its results are (you should see those as messages in the error console)

Comment: yes... first check whether dateText is not empty or undefined

Comment: Arun and Pekka: here is the result: Uncaught ReferenceError: dateText is not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work

```
var dateText = $(this).find("Date").text();

if( dateText && dateText.length===8){
            var year = dateText.substr(0,4);
            var month = dateText.substr(4,2) ;
            var day = dateText.substring(6,2);
            var newDate = new Date(year, month, day);
}else{
   dateText='TBD';
   newDate='TBD';
}
```

Comment: Hey Charlie: the TBD is kicking in but the dates being displayed are the same as above. I'm thinking this comes back to the problem of only have about half of the items containing the 'date' element. Should I implement a for loop to control the number of items parsed?

Comment: don't follow problem... idea of the `if` is it will set `TDB` if missing the element in xml, or if it returns string with length less than 8 characters, or no text. Might need `$.trim` if there is any whitespace in dates in xml

Comment: Every date beside the TDB is display as:Mon Jul 03 2017 instead of the date I createdm the dates im parsing and putting in the new date() object are all in either 2013 or 2014 so the date format isnt working with my input.

Comment: OK...you really need to start using `console.log(someVariable)` to look at variables within the code to see if they are what you think they are. Open browser console to see output

Comment: Ok, I added console.log(newDate) and console.log(dateText). When I ran the page in the browser this message came up: Uncaught ReferenceError: newDate is not defined

Comment: ok...so work backwards to find out why...if update plunker demo (the one I started) with revised xml and new code can help more...please leave out all the catgory url stuff...just point to data.xml file which contains new xml format

Comment: can also set break points in console...and walk through each step to see every variable at that point in code

Comment: Ok I narrowed it down thanks to your help...the console.log is returning inconsistent data. for the first 15+ it is in the yyyymmdd format, then after that it is in yymmdd, then finally the "Date" element is undefined. So it is must be due to the fact that the admin of the feed has not updated all of the events with a "Date" tag. Is there a way to add a for loop to limit the number of items parsed? I tried it earlier but I am unsure where it should be placed.

Comment: can use jquery `:lt()` selector  `$(xml).find("item:lt(30)")` for example  http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/basic-filter-selectors/

Comment: Like this?  $(xml).find("item:lt(15)").each(function ()

Comment: yes....limits the collection of `item` elements to 15...index starts at 0...that collection is what will be looped over by `each`

Comment: So it looks like the issue is the: var dateText = $(this).find("Date").text(); is not capturing the entire date. for example it is getting "20131" instead of "20131210"

Comment: Ok figured it out just hand an additional variable unaccounted for. Now I can display the dates no problem! Just have to work on the sort function. Thank you for all the help!